# ¿Cómo ordeno los elementos de una lista numéricamente?

Tags: python, lista, python-3.7, ordenamiento

Al mezclar una lista mi código ordena bien excepto que devuelve los números así:

---

1. `['3', '10', '12', '7', '12'] => ['10', '12', '12', '3', '7']`
2. `['4', '7', '10', '11', '9'] => ['10', '11', '4', '7', '9']`

---

Del 10 al 13 los toma como si fueran '1' y por eso los ordena al principio *¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo para que no los registre así?*

Voy a poner el código para ejemplificar más el problema:

```
import random
import collections

PALOS = ['espada', 'corazon', 'rombo', 'trebol']
VALORES = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']

def crear_baraja():
    barajas = []
    for palo in PALOS:
        for valor in VALORES:
            barajas.append((palo, valor))

    return barajas

def obtener_mano(barajas, tamano_mano):
    mano = random.sample(barajas, tamano_mano)
    
    return mano

def merge_sort(lista):
    if len(lista)>1:
        medio=len(lista)//2
        izquierda=lista[:medio]
        derecha=lista[medio:]
        print(izquierda,'*' * 5, derecha)
        
        merge_sort(izquierda)
        merge_sort(derecha)

        i = 0
        j = 0          
        k = 0

        while i < len(izquierda) and j < len(derecha):
            if izquierda[i]<derecha[j]:
                lista[k]=izquierda[i]
                i+=1
            else:
                lista[k]=derecha[j]
                j+=1
            k += 1

        while i < len(izquierda):
            lista[k]=izquierda[i]
            i+=1
            k+=1

        while j < len(derecha):
            lista[k]=derecha[j]
            j+=1
            k+=1

        print(f'izquierda {izquierda}, derecha {derecha}')   
        print('-'*50)
        return lista

def main(tamano_mano, intentos):
    barajas = crear_baraja()

    manos = []
    for _ in range(intentos):
        mano = obtener_mano(barajas, tamano_mano)
        manos.append(mano)

    pares = 0
    for mano in manos:
        valores = []
        
        for carta in mano:
            valores.append(carta[1])
        print(f'los valores son{valores}')        
        print(merge_sort(valores))
        print('*'*50) 

    probabilidad_par = pares / intentos
    print(f'La probabilidad de obtener un par en una mano de {tamano_mano} barajas es {probabilidad_par}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tamano_mano = int(input('De cuantas barajas sera la mano: '))
    intentos = int(input('Cuantos intentos para calcular la probabilidad: '))
    main(tamano_mano, intentos)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que en la función `merge_sort()` en la parte del ordenamiento comparas los números como strings. Se compara el primer caracter del string, y el segundo **solo si es necesario.**

En este caso en [la tabla de caracteres de unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Character_reference_overview), el caracter `'1'` está antes que cualquier otro dígito. Por lo tanto las cadenas que empiecen con `'1'` son las que se van a ir de primero.

En la función `crear_baraja()` asegúrate que estés añadiendo números

```
barajas.append((palo, int(valor)))
```

De esta manera ordenar por el valor numérico de los elementos.

Comment: muchas gracias :) me ayudaste bastante