# ¿Cómo puedo detectar que una lista ordenada contiene solo números consecutivos?

Tags: python, lista

¿Cómo detecto si hay números consecutivos en una lista?

Debo determinar si una lista (ordernada previamente) está compuesta por números consecutivos.

Por ejemplo:

Una lista así desordenada:

```
[13, 11, 8, 12, 5]
```

después se ordena ([¿Cómo ordeno los elementos de una lista numéricamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386941/c%c3%b3mo-ordeno-los-elementos-de-una-lista-num%c3%a9ricamente)) así:

```
[5, 8, 11, 12, 13]
```

Sobre esta lista ordenada debo determinar si está compuesta por números consecutivos. He probado con el siguiente fragmento de código pero no me funciona:

```
for i in range(len(order_list)):
if order_list[i]==order_list[i-1]:
    print('corrida')
```

Comment: ¿Y qué quieres mostrar?, la cantidad de números consecutivos encontrados?, o listar en parejas los números, ¿o sólo que te diga si hay o no hay?

Comment: pues es que tiene que detectar si hay una corrida, después de eso se busca saber la probabilidad de encontrar una corrida dentro de un juego de barajas...ya tengo todo, solo me falta dejar bien esa parte de la corrida, que me parece la corrida son a partir de 3 números consecutivos, no?

Comment: Ah, ya entendí, entonces cuenta cuántas veces consecutivas hay números consecutivos, si hay uno que no es consecutivo entonces reinicias el contador. Por ejemplo, inicias un contador de corrida c = 0, luego ya que ordenaste, recorre la lista y por cada ves que encuentres el consecutivo en lugar de print(corrida) haz c=c+1, y pones print(corrida) si c > 1 (que sería 2 o más, y te sales del if porque puede estar al principio la corrida y con una que encuentre ya, pero no se te olvide que si es diferente el elemento i y el i -1 entonces pon de nuevo c=0

Answer (score 4):

El codigo que soluciona lo que necesitas es como sigue:
Se define la funcion EsCorrida que evalúa una lista de enteros.
La funcion recorre la lista desde el primer hasta el penultimo elemento. Para cada elemento le suma uno (order_list[i]+1) y lo compara con el elemento siguiente (order_list[i+1]) si es corrida este predicado debe cumplirse para todos los elementos

```
#Funcion que determina si la lista es una corrida
def EsCorrida(order_list) :
    if(len(order_list)==0) :
        return False
    for i in range(len(order_list)-1) :
        if ((order_list[i]+1) != (order_list[i+1])) :
            return False
    return True

#Datos de prueba
lista_ordenada = [1,2,3,4]

#Invoca la funcion para determinar si es corrida
if (EsCorrida(lista_ordenada)) :
    print("Es Corrida")
else :
    print("No es Corrida")
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tenemos una lista ordenada con m+1 numeros consecutivos:

```
[n, n+1, n+2, ..., n+m]
```

su suma sera:

```
n * (m + 1) + 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + m
```

La sumatoria sum([0, 1, ..., m]) se puede calcular como:

```
m * (m - 1) / 2
```

Por lo tanto, todo lo que tengo que hacer es sumar los elementos de la lista y compararlo con la formular antedicha. Si los valores coinciden, la lista es consecutiva:

La función que comprueba si la lista está enteramente compuesta de números consecutivos es:

```
def es_consecutivo(lista):
    n = len(lista)
    suma = n * min(lista) + n * (n - 1) / 2 if n > 0 else 0
    return sum(lista) == suma
```

**Demostración**

```
tests = [
    [],
    [1],
    [1,2],
    [2, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
    [10, 10, 10],
    [10, 10, 12, 12]
]

for test in tests:
    print(test, es_consecutivo(test))
```

produce

```
[] True
[1] True
[1, 2] True
[2, 1] True
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] True
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6] False
[10, 10, 10] False
[10, 10, 12, 12] False
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Cómo lo haces, normalmente, cuando estás jugando a las cartas?¿Primero ordenas las cartas y las vas contando una a una, reseteando el contador cuando cambia de valor?

Lo normal es pillar la primera carta y contar cuántas más tienen igual valor, y continúas así con las demás. Se puede hacer de este modo:

```py
cartas = [13, 11, 8, 12, 5]

jugada = {carta: cartas.count(carta) for carta in set(cartas)}
```

Aquí `jugada` es un diccionario que indica cuántas veces aparece cada carta. `cartas.count(carta)` cuenta las veces que aparece `carta` en `cartas`. Usamos `set(cartas)` para quitar las repeticiones.

Si la idea es saber si hay tres o más cartas iguales, se puede expresar con la función `any()` de este modo:

```py
hay_corrida = any(cartas.count(carta) >= 3 for carta in set(cartas))
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es comprobar si en la lista hay algún número consecutivo, por ejemplo [1, 4, 5, 9]

```
def algun_consecutivo(lista):
    return len([i for i in range(len(lista)-1) if lista[i] + 1 == lista[i + 1]]) != 0
```

En cambio si lo que buscas es comprobar si toda la lista es consecutiva, por ejemplo [1, 2, 3, 4]

```
def algun_consecutivo(lista):
    return len([i for i in range(len(lista)-1) if lista[i] + 1 == lista[i + 1]]) == len(lista) - 1
```

En ambos casos se asume que lista está ordenada